# Several CSS files do not show in live server VS Code, but do in Codepen

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, server, vscode-extensions, live

Unfortunately I can not proceed working in any CSS File as now changes are not showing in live server in VS code. On the other hand HTML file is working in live server.Every change I make in HTML file is showing in the live server. I have checked ritwickdey on Github [enter link description here](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server)https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server

However, the css file is showen fully in codepen.

I re-installed the live server and VS code. Reset JSON.settings in VS-code.

- issue with live server v5.7.5,
  ritwickdey.liveserver
- chrome: latest version
- Live server Port: 49486
- machine: Windows home 10 64bit
- Server:  mijnmodem.kpn.home
  Address:  fe80::b2ac:d2ff:fe61:3581

Anyone ever faced the same problem or know how to fix it that css file is showing in live server?

Comment: For an open source project with >1k open issues (many similar to yours), https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues your only hope is someone forks it and casts some magic spells.

Comment: Lex Li, thank you for your response and useful link. Yes I have visited github before.  I have to give it a try again. Just watch a Youtube video about why VS code live server is not working, again followed instructions, but nope:(  I will research further

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in order to copy the relative link of the css.style file into link href="css/styles.css".
I could not figure it out before, because 1 other css file is loading in live server. Outside the online courses I
had so far I just getting started to build a website in VS-code.
So I'm bit unformaliar with VS-code.
See below links to solve issue when CSS file is not working in live server.

[My ccs file is not working in
live server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0_FKph6mZE&list=PLSabNJ3PEzP0CCLrukT5Yv56cjIdt0urF&index=11)

[Keep CSS file inside the vscode workspace.](https://%20github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/2351)